# Plotting GRIB data as a map with more than 360 degrees of longitude using R

Tags: r, plot, latitude-longitude, grib

I am trying to automatically grab data on wave height forecast and build plots similar [this one](http://hmc.hydromet.ru/sea/waves/images/00_hww+012.png).

Using R, I could download the data and plot it using:

```
library(rgdal)
library(fields)

ftp.string <- "ftp://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/waves//20130205.t00z/nww3.HTSGW.grb"
#this link may become broken with time, as folders are removed after some time. just edit the date to reflect the most recent day at the time you run these lines

download.file(ftp.string, "foo.grb", mode="wb")

grib <- readGDAL("foo.grb")
is.na(grib$band1) <- grib$band1 > 100
image(grib, col=(tim.colors(15)), attr=1)
```

However, if you take a closer look at the link I posted above, you'll notice a subtile difference: the plot from the link spans more than 360 degrees in longitude.

This is important for what I'm doing as it allows me to easily check for swells on all oceans within the same plot - this is much harder if only 360 degrees are shown at a time, as that forcibly results in one of the oceans being cut.

Despite all my best efforts, I can't find a way to plot more than 360 degrees, as the GRIB format is 'too smart' to allow that (this is not just offsetting the data, but instead repeating a part of it).

Any insights will be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Easy enough to do this with tools in raster, crop() one side with an extent() them offset it and paste to the side of the original ( I forget the last two functions, can make an example later if still necessaray).

Comment: `merge` you are thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more naive approach would be to create a second dataset, with an offset of 360°:

```
grib2 <- grib
grib2@bbox[1, ] <- grib2@bbox[1, ] - 360
image(grib, col=(tim.colors(15)), attr=1, xlim=c(-360,360))
image(grib2, add=TRUE, col=(tim.colors(15)), attr=1)
```

[image]

And you can play with `xlim` to center it the way you want:

```
image(grib, col=(tim.colors(15)), attr=1, xlim=c(-270,90))
image(grib2, add=TRUE, col=(tim.colors(15)), attr=1)
```

[image]

Here it works because the data is on a regular grid so there is no need for interpolation, otherwise of course, @Spacedman solution is to be preferred.

Comment: @ plannapus: sweet, it works just fine for what I'm trying to do. I'm ok with naive... thnkx!

Answer (score 5):

I would load your data into a raster stack from the `raster` package and then use the `merge` and `crop` functions. Basically you duplicate the raster, shift it 360 degrees, then merge that with itself, then crop it to taste. Here's a function:

```
require(raster)
wwrap <- function(g,xmax=720){
  gE = extent(g)

  shiftE = extent(360,720,gE@ymin, gE@ymax)
  g2 = g
  extent(g2)=shiftE

  gMerge = merge(g,g2)

  crop(gMerge,extent(0,xmax,gE@ymin, gE@ymax))
}
```

And here's some usage:

```
> gstack = stack("foo.grb")
> gstack[gstack>100] = NA
> gstack2 = wwrap(gstack,xmax=460)
> plot(gstack2)
> plot(gstack2[[1]])
> plot(gstack2[[61]])
```

Probably more efficient to shift and crop the raster first, then merge, but this is a start and it only takes a few seconds to run on your raster.

If all you care about is plotting then it might be easier to write a function that plots it twice, once with a shift in extent. But that would have to be done for each band in your raster....

```
wraplot <- function(g,xmax=720){
  gE = extent(g)
  ## to setup the plot
  worldWrap = extent(0,xmax,gE@ymin, gE@ymax)
  rWrap = raster(nrows=1,ncols=1,ext=worldWrap)
  rWrap[]=NA
  plot(rWrap)
  ## first part
  plot(g,add=TRUE)
  ## setup and plot it again
  shiftE = extent(360,720,gE@ymin, gE@ymax)
  cropE = extent(360,xmax,gE@ymin, gE@ymax)
  extent(g)=shiftE
  g=crop(g,cropE)
  plot(g,add=TRUE)
}
```

Then you do:

```
wraplot(gstack[[1]])
```

Check out all the features of the `raster` package.

Comment: What he said :), rotate() may also be worth a look but that is very limited in scope.

Comment: @ Spacedman: using your 1st suggestion I get stoped at **>gMerge = merge(g,g2)  >Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  :  different origin**, and with your 2nd suggestion I get a map with the correct longitude span, but with only the continents in green and nothing else... Can you help me a little more? Thanks

Comment: All I can say for your first problem is that if I paste the exact code I gave you into my system then I get no errors and I see the plots. For the second problem, I suspect this is because you might notice I've not tried to replace the >100 values with NA.

Comment: I've added the NA replacement to my answer. Now I see swirly oceans.

Comment: @ Spacedman: Even with your updated answer I still get the same compareRaster error... I don't really know what to do about it

Comment: First, have you tried updating the raster package? If that fails then we need to find out why raster thinks these rasters have a different origin...

Comment: @ Spacedman: ok, with a little fiddling I did get your solution to work. The problem was that you had set the wwrap function to shift the extent of the raster to 360-720, but somehow the original data's extent is -0.625 to 359.375... hence, there was a gap when merging the two objects. I edited your answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: It never seems clear if the extent of a raster includes half a cell width at the edges. You should probably update raster anyway.

Comment: Raster was up-to-date already. I don't know why my edits to your answer are not displayed... do they need to be accepted?